# Why Symfony 3 load so slow on XAMPP

Tags: php, symfony, xampp

I have an project wrote on Symfony3. It located on hosting and on localhost (xampp). 
My questions is next: why is so big difference between load time on hosting and on localhost (1234 ms vs. 15285 ms).

What should I do to make Symfony load a little bit faster on my localhost?

Comment: is xdebug profiler on? check in php.ini.

Comment: I have Xdebug on localhost activated and the php runtime is 10x slower than on my production server. So if you have Xdebug, that's why.